# CUDA install issues 22.04 lts

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I've just updated to ubuntu 22.04, and I'm trying to update my cuda install. However, I may have managed to mess up my packages. "Unable to correct problems,  you have held broken packages." I may have done something wrong when trying to purge an old install.

I'm trying to install cuda and cuda toolkit via https://developer.nvidia.com/, and it stalls on the last step. Trying to install directly from apt gives the same error (see below).

Please help. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
(base) xxx@xxx:~$ sudo apt install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-515 : Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 515.65.01) but 470.103.01-1 is to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 515.65.01) but 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

(base) xxx@xxx:~$ apt-cache policy nvidia-modprobe
nvidia-modprobe:
  Installed: 470.103.01-1
  Candidate: 470.103.01-1
  Version table:
     515.65.01-0ubuntu1 450
        450 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local  Packages
 *** 470.103.01-1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

(base) xxx@xxx:~$ apt-cache policy nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings:
  Installed: 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     515.65.01-0ubuntu1 450
        450 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local  Packages
 *** 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

(base) xxx@xxx:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Hmm... looks messy to me... To find something that "works":  Work in recovery mode; Try uninstalling everything nvidia, then start over. Try latest (515?), if that fails, clean out everything again, then try the next less recent version. Repeat until you find something that actually works. I'm currently running the 470 version due to similar issues in attempts to "upgrade" (I'm still on 20.04 though, due to seeing too many issues here with 22.04)

Comment: @Hannu It definitely is messy! I'll try to purge everything cuda and nvidia and see if that fixes it... but I think I already tried that...

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to correct the problem directly with apt, but the following steps worked to fix my cuda install:

1. Purge all nvidia and cuda drivers (sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-* && sudo apt remove --purge cuda*)
2. Install cuda via Nvidia's sources, using the RUN local file, not the deb package. On the first run, it successfully installed the nvidia driver, but failed to install toolkit
3. Run the RUN file a second time, just selecting the toolkit.

These steps solved my issues. Hope it helps someone else.